# How to reset 'new' and 'updated' flags without visiting a node page?

Tags: views, nodes

In my drupal site I have a content type that has its nodes visible only in a view and they have always the '*new*' (or '*updated*') flag up for all users.

How can I reset the flags without visiting the node page?
Is there a function to tell drupal "*this user has seen this node*"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`node_tag_new()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.module/function/node_tag_new/7) for that

> Updates the 'last viewed' timestamp of the specified node for current user.

e.g.

```
node_tag_new($node);
```

Answer (score -2):

Check out the theme function theme_mark:

```
function theme_mark($variables) {
  $type = $variables['type'];
  global $user;
  if ($user->uid) {
    if ($type == MARK_NEW) {
      return ' <span class="marker">' . t('new') . '</span>';
    }
    elseif ($type == MARK_UPDATED) {
      return ' <span class="marker">' . t('updated') . '</span>';
    }
  }
}
```

You can use that in a module to override the marking of your nodes. So if you define mymodule_theme_mark like:

```
function mymodule_theme_mark($variables) {
  $type = $variables['type'];
  global $user;
  if ($user->uid) {
    if ($type == MARK_NEW && (NOT YOUR NODE VIEW TYPE) ) {
      return ' <span class="marker">' . t('new') . '</span>';
    }
    elseif ($type == MARK_UPDATED && (NOT YOUR NODE VIEW TYPE)) {
      return ' <span class="marker">' . t('updated') . '</span>';
    }
  }
}
```

That should get you close to where you need to be.

Comment: Implementing business logic in theme layer is never a good practice.